# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect. - ProtectedData.Unprotect()

Tags: c#, sqlite, google-chrome, cryptography

I am trying to write a simple C# console application that will save my chrome passwords. I know that my login data is stored in `C:\Users\USER\Appdata\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data` and the passwords are encrypted but can be decrypted as long as the current user is running the program.

When I try to decrypt the passwords using the Unprotect() method, I get the following error:

`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The parameter is incorrect`

Here is my code:

```
 public void decrypt()
    {

        //Create a temp file to read from so database isn't locked
        string source = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data";
        string target = @"tmp\backup";
        File.Copy(source, target);


        SQLiteConnection sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source="+ target);
        try
        {
            sqlite.Open(); 
            SQLiteCommand cmd = sqlite.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins"; 
            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                //Decrypt password. Problem arises here
               var plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedData.Unprotect((byte[])reader["password_value"], null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
            }


            reader.Close();
            sqlite.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

The database seems to be valid because I can grab the username, host names..etc, but I simply cannot decrypt my passwords to plain text. I am logged in as the current user.

Comment: im having a similar issue. Did you figure something out to solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I noticed that not all passwords throw exception. If you catch `CryptographicException` and continue the process for other passwords, you can decrypt most of them. Has anyone solved it?

Comment: i know its late i am also having the same issue and i have a hint but still not managed to solve it the passwords that have exceptions of cryptography are those who are sync from cloud and not saved locally . .i you experiment to save a new password locally it will be decrypted by above method